# Input lag sshing to raspberry pi 3b while its running docker

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, docker, raspbian

On my raspberry 3B, ssh from another pc to it works fine until i start a docker image. Currently i have containers of portrain, pihole, and nextcloud on the Pi, but the issue arises whichever container i start running. Then there is up to 3 seconds lag randomly hitting when i type commands using ssh directly to the Pi (host). The problem vanishes as soon I stop the containers.

Info:
- Raspberry Pi 3B running latest Raspbian
- Raspberry connected using ethernet
- Docker using bridge mode for network
- Terminal directly on the host working fine.
- Login is fast. Only inside the ssh enviroment typing lags

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here.

I tried to `ping $ROUTERIPADDR` and i see random From xxx.xxx.xx.xx icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable.

The IP address is related to a network interface generated by docker containers. You can see them with `ifconfig`, should be something as veth...

As soon as i stop those interfaces with `ifconfig veth down`, laggyness disappers.